# How does gettext deal with a/an or d'/de?

Tags: localization, internationalization, gettext

Imagine this string for translation:

"Your path is blocked by a %s".

What if the variable is "anaconda".  Now it should be "Your path is blocked by an %s".

How does gettext cope with this, or how is the client programmer supposed to cope with this, or how do other systems cope with this?

Imagine this string:

"%s's Page".

We want to pass in "Brian" or "Jim" or "Lucinda". All well and good.

But in the French translation this is:

"Page de %s".

For Jean-Paul or Claudette this is fine but what about poor Anais?  She needs "Page d'Anais", not "Page de Anais".

Does gettext cope with this?  What's the standard practice?

Comment: Have you tried any of these cases?

Comment: "%s's Page". won't always work in English either. If the name ends in a hard s then usually you just add an apostrophe. e.g. Joneses'

Comment: I think it's fair to say that gettext does not deal with this problem.

Answer (score 3):

As you expect, gettext does not help you build grammatically-correct strings. Even when you don't have problems in English, constructing display text programmatically is a big localizability no-no as language-specific issues may crop up. If it's manageable you should probably have separate strings for each case, such as "Your path is blocked by a dinosaur", "Your path is blocked by a bunny", "Your path is blocked by an anaconda" etc. It means plenty of duplication, but translation systems help automate the process through the use of translation memories and even in the more sophisticated cases automatic translation (which translators just need to proofread and amend if needed).

Your "Page d'Anais"/"Page de Claudette" is a great example. The only solution in such cases is to store the format string in the localizable string table (and it sounds like you are already are doing that) so that localizers can come up with a workable solution. (for example "Page de : Anais" albeit not very pretty works in every case, so they will localize "%s's Page" as "Page de : %s"). But localizers do need to understand where this format strings will go and how it's constructed, so you need to make this clear.

One of the most widely mistranslated strings is "%n of %n" (used for printing pages, as in page "1 of 4") which without context is often translated completely wrong. E.g. in French a literal translation is "1 de 4" which is meaningless in this context, it should be "1 sur 4".